# Action Keystroke GUI For Mac OS X

Tags: java

EDIT: This post was edited due to the automated "Title" keyword matching function of this site that caused some confusion for us humans with the word "AutoHotKey"

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate, it needs a GUI not here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153930/autohotkey-equivalent-for-os-x

Comment: If none of the answers in the linked question solve your problem, please **edit** your question here to explain in more detail what you need and why the answers in the linked questions don't help. It might help to not assume that macOS users know about AHK.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for two different things. You first want some scripting for automating UI tasks. That should be covered by the answers given in the duplicate question, as well as by Apple's own Accessibility scripting functionality.

Comment: There's no "automated title keyword matching function."  The confusion is that you keep asking for an Mac alternative to a Windows program with some sort of GUI and then include coding for the Windows program.  What might be better is you explain what want to accomplish *without* the references to Windows because it's like going into a steak restaurant trying to find an equivalent of a vegan dish by describing how it's cooked.

Comment: The second thing you want is a GUI for running these automated scripts, right? I would recommend just using Python / Java and building an app that calls these automation scripts. It should be possible to have the automation scripts not steal focus. That way your control GUI is distinct from your automation scripting. Makes cross platform porting easier.

It sounds like AHK does both halves of this in windows. To the best of my knowledge there's not a one stop resource like that for macos

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s3teehz43luqrii/Ask_Keywords.png?dl=0  If one person don't understand something they are best not to comment and leave it to someone with multiple levels of understanding, it's not a steak restaurant with only one level of understanding that we are in. In other forums I go out of my way to help any user, no matter how dumb or stupid their question may sound.

Comment: *In other forums I go out of my way to help any user, no matter how dumb or stupid their question may sound*  That's good because you understand how this all works.  What we are trying to help you understand is that you haven't clarified what *doesn't* make this a dupe.  As of yet, have you reviewed patrix's comment and *explained why* the linked answer(s) can't help you?  Saying "you want a GUI" is quite vague.  Your "edit" doesn't clarify anything, it just makes theoretical judgement about why it's closed.  Please edit your question with details so we can help you.